# Assumption in a convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Im in the middle of a proof of the fact that  for a>0, if lim $x_n$ = a,  then  lim $\sqrt{x_n}$ = $\sqrt{a}$.

I'm in the step that i use   $| \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a} |$ =  $ \frac{|x_n -  a|}{ \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a}}$ to estimate an upper-bound that can be as small as i want ( smaller than an arbitrary $\varepsilon$ ) and hence conclude, by transitivity, that    $| \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a} |$ can also be.

I know that $x_n$ converges to some positive value a and from that, i know that
$\exists 0 < M < a $ such that   $x_n$ is eventually lower-bounded by M.

Should i be able to conclude imediately from this fact that $\sqrt{x_n}$ is eventually lower-bounded by $\sqrt{M}$  and use that in the proof ?

Would that be skipping too many steps, or maybe assuming in advance that $\sqrt{x_n} $converges  when in fact we don't know that yet ?

If that fact about $\sqrt{x_n}$ indeed follows imediately, i would then infer that
$\exists n_1 $ such that $n > n_1   \to \sqrt{x_n}$ is lower-bounded by $\sqrt{M}$, and then from that i would conclude that:
    $ n > n_1  \to   \frac{|x_n -  a|}{ \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a}}  \leq   \frac{|x_n -  a|}{ \sqrt{M} + \sqrt{a}} $  .

Then i would apply the same reasoning for $|x_n -  a|$, picking a $n_2$ such that 
$\forall n > n_2 $   $ |x_n -a| < \varepsilon . (\sqrt{M} + \sqrt{a}) $ and then easily conclude the proof :

$n $> max{$n_1,n_2$} $\to$   $| \sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a} | <  \frac{\varepsilon (\sqrt{M} + \sqrt{a})}{(\sqrt{M} + \sqrt{a})} = \varepsilon$

I know this proof can be done way easier, by noticing that

$ \frac{|x_n -  a|}{ \sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{a}}  \leq \frac{|x_n -  a|}{ \sqrt{a}}  $.

But my doubt lies exactly in not knowing if in this kind of proof, i can conclude imediately that   $\sqrt{x_n}$ is eventually lower-bounded by $\sqrt{M}$  from the fact that  $x_n$ is eventually lower-bounded by M and then use that to show that   lim $\sqrt{x_n}$ = $\sqrt{a}$ .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please state more steps, or at least a sketch of your proof please? I would use the fact that the square root function is monotonic to conclude that $\sqrt{x_n}$ has a lower bound when $x_n$ has a lower bound.

Comment: Sure, if $x_n \ge M \ge 0$, then $\sqrt{x_n} \ge \sqrt{M}$ since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is increasing.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on $\sqrt{}$ being increasing and hence being able to conclude $a \geq b \to \sqrt{a} \geq \sqrt{b} $ ?

Answer (score 1):

**An other way :** We have that $$\left|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt a\right|<\sqrt{|x_n-a|}.$$

Indeed, if $0\leq x_n\leq a$,
$$\left|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}\right|^2= a-x_n-2ax_n\leq a-x_n$$
and if $0<a\leq x_n$

$$\left|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}\right|^2= x_n-a-2ax_n\leq x_n-a.$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then,
$$|x_n-a|<\varepsilon^2$$
if $n>N$ for a certain $N\in\mathbb N$. We can finally conclude that if $n>N$,
$$\left|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}\right|\leq \sqrt{|x_n-a|}<\sqrt{\varepsilon^2}=\varepsilon.$$

Q.E.D.